# Android FCM push notification with Appcelerator Cloud Services not working in PROD env

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, appcelerator, firebase-cloud-messaging

I successfully integrated GCM in development with Appcelerator Cloud Services, but when I switch to production, app keeps saying "Failed receiving GCM SenderId." I tried to create/delete Firebase app/project several times, but nothing helped.
 Can anyone please help?
Thank you

Comment: Are you using GCM or FCM? From your given context it looks like you've used both.

Comment: Hello Garre, I use Firebase...

Comment: Can you give more information? Your app is giving that error. What is your app? The Appcelerator app(client)? Or your server app? Are you using hyperloop? Are you using a module? Do you get the message on Android or iOS or both? So many questions so little context...

Comment: Something went wrong with that app, so I created new project(Titanium classic app), copy there all source files from original folder and it works for now... Thank you.